# Create bindable property in subclass

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I have subclassed NSLevelIndicator as I need a different visual representation of it. I also added a property which I need to be bindable (a color).

Does anybody know how to create properties which are bindable using Interface Builder? I bound all other values I need (min and max value as well as the current value. Just that one is missing.

I'm currently working with Xcode 6 Beta 6.

Comment: If it is KVO and KVC compliant then it should be bindable. Have you tried binding to it in Interface Builder? (autocomplete probably won't work)

Comment: I couldn't try to bind it in Interface Builder because I can't see this property in Binding Inspector (which is the problem).

Comment: IB can't automatically detect properties to which you can bind. It should be a text field in which you can type a name. Have you tried typing in this property name?

Comment: @Vervious I don't really get what you mean. I'm not talking about binding a property to an existing binding (e.g. "textColor" of a text field), but of defining own bindings (e.g. "myOwnColor") which can be bound to source code properties.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. I thought that you were talking about making source code properties bindable instead of making Interface Builder object properties exposed to interface builder.